# Get background button and apply this color to another one

Tags: java, android, android-studio, colors, background

I have a project on android studio and I need to get the background color of my button to apply the color to another.

I tried this :

```
ColorDrawable BgColor = (ColorDrawable) btn_next.getBackground();
btn_filRouge.setBackgroundColor(BgColor);
```

I want to convert ColorDrawable to int. Or to get the color into int directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to convert ColorDrawable to int. Or to **get** the **color** into int
>   directly.

You can't convert ColorDrawable to int, but you can follow the second solution, The answer is in your question, you can use `getColor()` :

```
ColorDrawable bgColor = (ColorDrawable) btn_next.getBackground();
int color = bgColor.getColor();
```

For more details check the documentation of [**ColorDrawable**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable)